# package libprocess-cpp-dev missing in 18.04

Tags: package-management, 18.04, development

I'm trying to build an application that requires `libprocess-cpp-dev`.
There is [no available version for 18.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=libprocess-cpp-dev).

I also tried to to look for an alternative package with the same header files using `apt-file`:

```
apt-file search /usr/include/core/
```

but there are none with file `/usr/include/core/posix/child_process.h`

What can I do to get the files I need on 18.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Required package exists for trusty (14.04LTS), xenial (16.04LTS), artful (17.10) and cosmic (18.10) Ubuntu releases.

Ubuntu supports upgrade from LTS release to next LTS and next nonLTS and from nonLTS to next release.

Since bionic (18.04) is LTS release it's cleaner to use packages from previous LTS release due to support time.
Look into `/etc/apt/sources.list` and chose minimal number of repositories to use from xenial:

```
deb http://hr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
deb http://hr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
```

then duplicate those lines and replace `bionic` with `xenial`:

```
deb http://hr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
deb http://hr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb http://hr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
deb http://hr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
```

You could use artful or cosmic release, but using cosmic would upgrade installation.
This way system behaves like it's xenial upgraded to bionic.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a setup script for your system, you could try something like this :

```
PKG_OK=$(dpkg-query -W --showformat='${Status}\n' 2>&1 *libprocess-cpp-dev* |grep "install ok installed")
if [ "" == "$PKG_OK" ]; then
  echo -n "- libprocess library <file> "
  sudo apt-get install -yq libprocess-cpp-dev
  echo " - done."
else
  echo "- libprocess library already installed"
fi

# check again and if fail, try another way
PKG_OK=$(dpkg-query -W --showformat='${Status}\n' 2>&1 *libprocess-cpp-dev* |grep "install ok installed")
if [ "" == "$PKG_OK" ]; then
  echo -n "- > append to sources.list file the xenial libs and try again."
  sudo echo "deb http://hr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
  sudo echo "deb http://hr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
  sudo apt-get install -yq libprocess-cpp-dev
  echo " - done."
else
  echo "- libprocess library already installed"
fi
```

This worked for me